# Git Gutter not working in Sublime 3 on Windows 10

Tags: git, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I used GitGutter in my sublime text in using Ubuntu and it works. I shifted to windows and installed GitGutter. The problem is every time I make a changes into my code it doesn't show the highlighted line that's been modified or removed. I am using a Material Theme for sublime text maybe because of the color scheme? But when I installed material theme in sublime using ubuntu with GitGutter and everything works fine.

I notice some error or warning sign below in my sublime near the line and column indicator. Here is the error below

> GitGutter: "git --version" failed with "[WinError 2] The system cannot
>   find the file specified"

This is the settings in my GitGutter

```
// GitGutter Settings - User
{
    "debug": true,
    "git_binary": "C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe"
}
```

Appreciate if someone can help.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please create an issue at https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter/issues